# iptables rules apply with delay

Tags: linux, iptables, wifi-hotspot, iptables-redirect

I'm using iptables to block Internet (by redirecting to an internal server) access on devices connected to my hotspot. That's my command:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -s 192.168.43.51 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.43.1:12345
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp -s 192.168.43.51 ! --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.43.1:12345
```

192.168.43.51 is the device I'm blocking and 192.168.43.1:12345 is the internal server. So it's working but there is a delay between real blocking and command execution. For example while I'm downloading a file, I am executing that command but file keeps downloading for a 5-15(apprx.) seconds while the user can consume some additional data. How can it be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is solution that worked:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -s 192.168.43.51 ! -d 192.168.43.1 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 2):

Block it in the OUTPUT rule except to your IP too.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.43.51 ! -d 192.168.43.1 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD  -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -s 192.167.43.51 ! -d 192.168.43.1 -j DROP
```

Comment: Could you please write a full command? I'm pretty new to iptables stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Edited it a few times to get it right.

Comment: Nope, it's not helping. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Odd. I suspect it must have to be something related with optimisations and/or conntrack, however I have no idea how to get around it.

Comment: I remembered there are the RELATED rules. In 20 minutes I can give you an example if you have not find it by them (dining here)

Comment: thanks, currently googling on conntrack. I'll write if I'll find anything

Comment: I edited the answer, does it work now?

Comment: Nope:LISHED,RELATED -s 192.167.43.51 ! -d 192.168.43.1 -j DROP                     <
Bad argument `ESTABLISHED,RELATED'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Comment: corrected the command

Comment: Now it executes but it still ain't working.

Comment: a last try, try changing the INPUT for the OUTPUT chain. If that does not work, I am out of ideas.

Comment: silly me. The Chain is FORWARD, you are routing them

Comment: edited it again.

Comment: Result is the same. Thanks you for your efforts.